# Installing racket packages as native executables on linux

Tags: linux, package, racket, raco

Is there a way to install a racket package either:

- as a statically linked native executable?
- have raco install it to specific path where it can be packaged and distributed as native linux distribution package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two questions here. The first one being if it's possible to create a racket package as a statically linked native executable. If you mean a single executable with all the libraries statically linked, the answer is no. You can, however, create a racket distribution of your application that you can then install on machines without racket. See https://docs.racket-lang.org/raco/exe-dist.html

The second question is if you can use raco install to install the above mentioned package and the answer is no. raco will install pkgs, libraries into the system, for use with racket but not an application in a system-wide manner.

My advice is to use `raco distribute` and then use a system installer get it into the target system. For arch linux, I would create a `raco distribute` of my application and then I would create an AUR to distribute my application to my target users.

Comment: Wait, I thought you could make a single executable with the `raco exe` command: https://docs.racket-lang.org/raco/exe.html Or am I missing something?

Comment: @LeifAndersen Yes, but that still has dependencies on racket, i.e. you still need racket libraries somewhere on the system. That's why `raco distribute` was added, at least that's my understanding of things.